# How to translate a table driven CRC implmentation to a bitwise implmentation?

Tags: c++, crc

I have some CRC methods that I need to test. These methods were not written by myself.  The best way I can see doing that is to implemented the CRC algorithm using a different technique and then compare results.

Currently all of the CRC routines are written in a table driven format. I can't seem to find any tutorial explaining how one could translated the code into a bitwise implementation. I'm sure this is my lack of understand of how CRCs work.

If somebody could provide an example of the same CRC routine implemented 2 different ways that would be great.  I've searched on the internet and haven't found much that has aided me in my issue.

Here is example code of one of the CRC algorithms that I need to test:

```
// This table implements the EPO CRC16 algorithm with a polynomial of 0x17531
static const uint16 s_EPOCRC16Table[] =
{
   0x0000U, 0x7531U, 0xEA62U, 0x9F53U, 0xA1F5U, 0xD4C4U, 0x4B97U, 0x3EA6U,
   0x36DBU, 0x43EAU, 0xDCB9U, 0xA988U, 0x972EU, 0xE21FU, 0x7D4CU, 0x087DU,
   0x6DB6U, 0x1887U, 0x87D4U, 0xF2E5U, 0xCC43U, 0xB972U, 0x2621U, 0x5310U,
   0x5B6DU, 0x2E5CU, 0xB10FU, 0xC43EU, 0xFA98U, 0x8FA9U, 0x10FAU, 0x65CBU,
   0xDB6CU, 0xAE5DU, 0x310EU, 0x443FU, 0x7A99U, 0x0FA8U, 0x90FBU, 0xE5CAU,
   0xEDB7U, 0x9886U, 0x07D5U, 0x72E4U, 0x4C42U, 0x3973U, 0xA620U, 0xD311U,
   0xB6DAU, 0xC3EBU, 0x5CB8U, 0x2989U, 0x172FU, 0x621EU, 0xFD4DU, 0x887CU,
   0x8001U, 0xF530U, 0x6A63U, 0x1F52U, 0x21F4U, 0x54C5U, 0xCB96U, 0xBEA7U,
   0xC3E9U, 0xB6D8U, 0x298BU, 0x5CBAU, 0x621CU, 0x172DU, 0x887EU, 0xFD4FU,
   0xF532U, 0x8003U, 0x1F50U, 0x6A61U, 0x54C7U, 0x21F6U, 0xBEA5U, 0xCB94U,
   0xAE5FU, 0xDB6EU, 0x443DU, 0x310CU, 0x0FAAU, 0x7A9BU, 0xE5C8U, 0x90F9U,
   0x9884U, 0xEDB5U, 0x72E6U, 0x07D7U, 0x3971U, 0x4C40U, 0xD313U, 0xA622U,
   0x1885U, 0x6DB4U, 0xF2E7U, 0x87D6U, 0xB970U, 0xCC41U, 0x5312U, 0x2623U,
   0x2E5EU, 0x5B6FU, 0xC43CU, 0xB10DU, 0x8FABU, 0xFA9AU, 0x65C9U, 0x10F8U,
   0x7533U, 0x0002U, 0x9F51U, 0xEA60U, 0xD4C6U, 0xA1F7U, 0x3EA4U, 0x4B95U,
   0x43E8U, 0x36D9U, 0xA98AU, 0xDCBBU, 0xE21DU, 0x972CU, 0x087FU, 0x7D4EU,
   0xF2E3U, 0x87D2U, 0x1881U, 0x6DB0U, 0x5316U, 0x2627U, 0xB974U, 0xCC45U,
   0xC438U, 0xB109U, 0x2E5AU, 0x5B6BU, 0x65CDU, 0x10FCU, 0x8FAFU, 0xFA9EU,
   0x9F55U, 0xEA64U, 0x7537U, 0x0006U, 0x3EA0U, 0x4B91U, 0xD4C2U, 0xA1F3U,
   0xA98EU, 0xDCBFU, 0x43ECU, 0x36DDU, 0x087BU, 0x7D4AU, 0xE219U, 0x9728U,
   0x298FU, 0x5CBEU, 0xC3EDU, 0xB6DCU, 0x887AU, 0xFD4BU, 0x6218U, 0x1729U,
   0x1F54U, 0x6A65U, 0xF536U, 0x8007U, 0xBEA1U, 0xCB90U, 0x54C3U, 0x21F2U,
   0x4439U, 0x3108U, 0xAE5BU, 0xDB6AU, 0xE5CCU, 0x90FDU, 0x0FAEU, 0x7A9FU,
   0x72E2U, 0x07D3U, 0x9880U, 0xEDB1U, 0xD317U, 0xA626U, 0x3975U, 0x4C44U,
   0x310AU, 0x443BU, 0xDB68U, 0xAE59U, 0x90FFU, 0xE5CEU, 0x7A9DU, 0x0FACU,
   0x07D1U, 0x72E0U, 0xEDB3U, 0x9882U, 0xA624U, 0xD315U, 0x4C46U, 0x3977U,
   0x5CBCU, 0x298DU, 0xB6DEU, 0xC3EFU, 0xFD49U, 0x8878U, 0x172BU, 0x621AU,
   0x6A67U, 0x1F56U, 0x8005U, 0xF534U, 0xCB92U, 0xBEA3U, 0x21F0U, 0x54C1U,
   0xEA66U, 0x9F57U, 0x0004U, 0x7535U, 0x4B93U, 0x3EA2U, 0xA1F1U, 0xD4C0U,
   0xDCBDU, 0xA98CU, 0x36DFU, 0x43EEU, 0x7D48U, 0x0879U, 0x972AU, 0xE21BU,
   0x87D0U, 0xF2E1U, 0x6DB2U, 0x1883U, 0x2625U, 0x5314U, 0xCC47U, 0xB976U,
   0xB10BU, 0xC43AU, 0x5B69U, 0x2E58U, 0x10FEU, 0x65CFU, 0xFA9CU, 0x8FADU,
};

/**
 * This routine returns the CRC-16 of Cp_ptr.
 * This CRC routine is reversed to match the routine used in the EPO.
 *
 * @param  const uint8 *Cp_ptr - data pointer to the bit string to be calculated over
 * @param  const uint32 Len    - the number of bytes pointed to by Cp_ptr
 * @return the calculated 16-bit CRC
 * @ureq
 *    -# epoCRC16() shall calculate a 16-bit CRC on a block of data starting at an address of a specified length.
 *    -# epoCRC16() shall ASSERT if the passed in pointer is NULL.
 */
uint16 epoCRC16( const uint8 *Cp_ptr, const uint32 Len )
{
   ASSERT( Cp_ptr != NULL );

   // local variable
   uint16 crc = 0x0;

   // calculate the crc
   for ( uint16 i = Len; i > 0; i-- )
   {
      const uint8 TableIndex = ( *Cp_ptr ^ static_cast<uint8>( crc >> 8 ) );
      crc = static_cast<uint16>( crc << 8 );
      crc = ( crc ^ s_EPOCRC16Table[TableIndex] );
      Cp_ptr++;
   }

   return crc;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone actually use a CRC16. It's all CRC32 now.

Comment: I don't agree with your method of testing.  The best way to test this type of algorithm is to feed it inputs that you know the answer to and make sure it produces the correct values.

Comment: Anon Mail: while in theory that would work. I don't have any input where I know the valid CRC.  I think my method is valid as unless both implementations were coded wrong the same way the same data should not present the same CRC.

Comment: @Mysticial In 8- and 16-bit microcontrollers, nobody even wants such progress. These are used in over-the-wire protocols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need the CRC polynomial which you can find in either the second entry or the 128th entry of such a table, depending on the bit ordering of the CRC.  Or in this case you can find it in the comments, `0x17531`.  The `1` after the `x` there is the first term of the polynomial, which simply defines the length of the CRC.  It is dropped in the calculation.  You can find `0x7531` in the second entry of the table.

This routine (in C) generates the above table with just the polynomial:

```
void make_crc_table(unsigned poly, unsigned *table)
{
    unsigned n, k, crc;

    for (n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        crc = n << 8;
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ poly : crc << 1;
        table[n] = crc & 0xffff;
    }
}
```

It would be called thusly: `make_crc_table(0x7531, table)` where `table` is an array of 256 unsigned integers.

The bit-wise CRC routine looks about the same:

```
unsigned epobit(unsigned char *buf, unsigned len, unsigned poly)
{
    unsigned n, k, crc = 0;

    for (n = len; n > 0; n--) {
        crc ^= (*buf++ << 8);
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ poly : crc << 1;
    }
    return crc & 0xffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a tool, check out [pycrc](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/index_en.html), which has a code generator for any arbitrary CRC.

For an explanation on CRC computation, see [A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Bitise and tablewise CRC-16 can be compared by following source code with polynomial 0x17531 !

// CRC.cpp : 
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CRC.h"

#include "afx.h"
#include <conio.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

#define BUFLENGTH (0x100000*1)  //0x100000=1MB

void makeCRC16Table();
void crc16update(unsigned short &crc0, const void *data, int length);
void crc16updateBitwise(unsigned short &crc0, const void *data, int length);

static byte crc8Table[256];
static unsigned short crc16Table[256];
static unsigned long crc32Table[256];

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    unsigned char crc8=0x00;
    unsigned short crc16=0x0000;
    unsigned long crc32=0x00000000;

    byte *dataBuf = new byte[BUFLENGTH];
    if(dataBuf==0)
    {
        cout<<"Not enough memory allocation to dataBuf[] !";
        while(!_kbhit());
        return nRetCode;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<BUFLENGTH; i++)
        dataBuf[i]=i+1;

    makeCRC16Table();
    crc16=0x00;
    crc16update(crc16, dataBuf, BUFLENGTH);
    crc16=0x00;
    crc16updateBitwise(crc16, dataBuf, BUFLENGTH);

    delete[] dataBuf;

    while(!_kbhit());

    }

    return nRetCode;
}

void makeCRC16Table()
{
    /* generate a table for a byte-wise 16-bit CRC caculation on the polynomial ;
      */
    CString soutputfile=_T("crc16Table.txt");
    CString soutputbuffer;
    CStdioFile fileTarget( soutputfile, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite );
    int i,j;
    unsigned long poly, cc;
    /* terms of polynomial defining this crc (except x^16) */
    //static const byte pp[]={0,5,12};
    static const byte pp[]={0,2,15};

    /* make exclusive-or pattern from polynomial 0x1021 */
    poly=0;
    //for(i=0; i<sizeof(pp)/sizeof(byte); i++) 
    //  poly|=1<<pp[i];
    poly=0x7531;
    //poly=0x1021;
    //poly=0x8005;

    for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
        cc=i<<8; 
        for(j=0; j<8; j++) {
            cc=(cc&0x8000)?(poly^(cc<<1)):(cc<<1);  //MSB first transmission

        }
        crc16Table[i]=cc&0xffff;

        soutputbuffer.Format("%3d:%04X\n", i, crc16Table[i]);
        fileTarget.WriteString(soutputbuffer);
    }
    fileTarget.Close();
    //ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, soutputfile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}

void crc16update(unsigned short &crc0, const void *data, int length)
{
    CString soutputfile=_T("crc16.txt");
    cout<<"\n"<<soutputfile<<"\n";

    CString soutputbuffer, soutputbufferTotal;
    CStdioFile fileTarget( soutputfile, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite );

    int percentage=0, ntemp;
    unsigned short crc,crc1;
    const unsigned char *buf=(const unsigned char *)data;
    int i=0, j;
    crc=crc0;
    while(i<length) 
    {
        ntemp=i/(length/100);
        if(ntemp!=percentage)
        {
            soutputbuffer.Format("%d%% ", percentage );
            cout<<soutputbuffer;
            percentage=ntemp;
            if(ntemp<0)
                int nn=0;
        }

        crc1=crc;
        j = ((crc >> 8) ^ buf[i]) & 0xff;
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc16Table[j];

        soutputbuffer.Format("%d:%02X:%04X>%04X\n", i, buf[i], crc1, crc );
        fileTarget.WriteString(soutputbuffer);
        i++;
    }
    soutputbuffer.Format("\n%04X>%04X", crc1, crc );
    cout<<soutputbuffer;
    crc0=crc;
    fileTarget.Close();
    //ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, soutputfile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}

void crc16updateBitwise(unsigned short &crc0, const void *data, int length)
{
    CString soutputfile=_T("crc16BW.txt");
    cout<<"\n"<<soutputfile<<"\n";

    CString soutputbuffer;
    CStdioFile fileTarget( soutputfile, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite );

    static const byte BitTable[]={0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
    int percentage=0, ntemp;
    unsigned long poly;
    /* terms of polynomial defining this crc (except x^16) */
    //static const byte pp[]={0,5,12};//CCITT
    static const byte pp[]={0,2,15};//GENERAL

    /* make exclusive-or pattern from polynomial 0x1021 */
    int i;
    poly=0;
    //for(i=0; i<sizeof(pp)/sizeof(byte); i++) 
    //  poly|=1<<pp[i];
    //poly=0x8005;
    poly=0x7531;

    unsigned short crc,crc1;
    const unsigned char *buf=(const unsigned char *)data;
    byte a,b,c;
    crc=crc0;
    i=0;
    while(i<length) 
    {
        ntemp=i/(length/100);
        if(ntemp!=percentage)
        {
            soutputbuffer.Format("%d%% ", percentage );
            cout<<soutputbuffer;
            percentage=ntemp;
        }
        crc1=crc;
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            a=(crc&0x8000)?1:0;//x^16
            b=(buf[i]&BitTable[7-j])?1:0;////MSB first transmission 
            c=a^b;
            crc=(c?(poly^(crc<<1)):(crc<<1))&0xffff;
        }
        soutputbuffer.Format("%d:%02X:%04X>%04X\n", i, buf[i], crc1&0xffff, crc&0xffff );
        fileTarget.WriteString(soutputbuffer);
        i++;
    }
    soutputbuffer.Format("\n%04X>%04X", crc1&0xffff, crc&0xffff );
    cout<<soutputbuffer;
    crc0=crc;
    fileTarget.Close();
    //ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, soutputfile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```